# webots simulation synchronize

Tags: synchronization, webots

Does anyone know how to synchronize the 2 clocks of Webots? the one of the console and the environment clock? because I am trying to use the internal python clock to define rotational movements and I cannot rotate at the desired angles because of the asynchronous clocks

Answer (score 1):

Webots does not use the environment clock, it computes a "simulated time" based on the simulation events (mainly the physics discrete steps asked by the controller). Therefore, the controller and any library used by a Webots controller should use only the simulated time provided by Webots.

This can be achieved by calling the [wb_robot_get_time](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot#wb_robot_get_time) function which changes at each [wb_robot_step](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot#wb_robot_step) calls.